# Getting all the strings in a file that are separated by tabs

Tags: c++

I have a file that has multiple lines and on each line is data separated by tabs and I need to add this data to its corresponding array. How do I see if I have come across a tab so that I can know when the data ends.

Comment: `std::string data; std::getline(file, data, '\t');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), what do you think?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>

int main() {
    std::ifstream infile("inputfile.dat");
    std::list<std::string> stringarray;
    while(infile.good()) {
        stringarray.emplace_back();
        std::string& datum = stringarray.back();
        char data(0);
        while(infile.good()) {
            infile.get(data);
            if((data == '\t') || (data == '\n'))
                break;
            datum += data;
        } 
    }
    for(const std::string& string : stringarray)
        std::cout << string << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```